# Manually upgrading TeXLive version?

Tags: texlive, mactex

I reinstalled MacTeX-2015 yesterday to deal with some problems related to my recent "upgrade" to OS X 10.11 "El Capitan". Since reinstalling the TeXLive utility is giving me the message:

> Repository URL has a newer TeXLive Version. Your TeX Live version is
>   0, but your default repository URL appears to be for TeX Live 2015. 
>   You need to manually upgrade to a newer version of TeX Live, as there
>   will be no further updates for your version.

Clicking the upgrade button simply takes me to the MacTeX website. I would think that a fresh install of the latest version would remedy this, but that's apparently false since I have already done that. My current TeXLive version is 1.21.

Update:
I manually deleted all my installed distributions in /usr/local/texlive (leaving only /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local) and then reinstalled. That replaced the directory /usr/local/texlive/2015, but has not resolved the problem.

Comment: Is the message the same if you issue `sudo tlmgr update` from a terminal?

Answer (score 7):

Solution: Update TeXLive preferences to indicate new location of TeX programs in /Library/TeX/texbin/.

Thanks egreg for setting me on the right path.